# A disabled control in a DataGridCell is still editable

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with WPF and the [MaterialDesignInXAML tool kit](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)

I want to disable a control(in this case, a checkbox accessed by the DataGridCell.Content property) in a certain DataGridCell. However, even if the checkbox's color turns to gray(I think it means the control is disabled), I still can edit it when I enter the cell.

I have tried to disable the DataGridCell itself, and it works, which means the checkbox control in the cell can not be edited anymore. But I still want to know why I can't just disable the checkbox?

```
private void ButtonForDisablingCheckbox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The following line can reach the purpose of disabling the control in the cell
    // DataGridForSchema.GetCell(0, 3).IsEnabled = false;

    // The following line can not reach that purpose
    (DataGridForSchema.GetCell(0, 3).Content as CheckBox).IsEnabled = false;

}
```

ps: the GetCell method is in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/709092a6-f68f-41f0-9282-fcd6caa0bb1a/finding-checkbox-id-in-datagrid?forum=wpf) (the first answer)

**Here are some photos which show the situation**

before I click the button for disabling checkbox:
[image: before I click the button for disabling checkbox]

after I click the button(you can notice the checkbox's color(in the first row) is changed：
[image: after I click the button(you can notice the checkbox's color(in the first row) is changed]

I can still check the seemingly disabled checkbox：
[image: I can still check the seemingly disabled checkbox]

Thanks for your help in advance!